# Problem with imports in NodeJS ( Failed to resolve module specifier )

Tags: javascript, node.js, ton

I don't understand why my Test application don't work.

I have `index.html`, `index.cjs`, `/public/js/app.js`.

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script type="module" src="./js/app.js"></script>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Test HTML page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.cjs`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Application started and Listening on port 3000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

`app.js`

```
import TonWeb from 'tonweb';
import { getHttpEndpoint } from "@orbs-network/ton-access";

console.log("import works!");
```

In VsCode i run `node .` , open browser and get this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tonweb". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

When i set whole path `(import TonWeb from './node_modules/tonweb/tonweb.js';)`

I get this error: `GET http://localhost:3000/js/node_modules/tonweb/tonweb.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I even tried jsDelivr: `import TonWeb from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tonweb@0.0.62/src/index.min.js';`

But got this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tonweb@0.0.62/src/index.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

How i can import and use tonweb?

Comment: looks like you're trying to use a `nodejs` module in a web browser

Comment: I'm total newbie. It's not possible? How i can send some data from nodejs module to my html file?

Comment: I'm not saying that module isn't possible in a web page (it may or may not be, I'm like you, haven't read the documentation for it), just not how you're attempting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I even tried jsDelivr: import TonWeb from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tonweb@0.0.62/src/index.min.js';

`tonweb` isn't a es module. it's built and distributed in cjs.
therefore you would need some kind of build process such as webpack, esbuild or any other build tool.

An other (simpler) alternative solution is to just use any cdn delivery network such as jsdeliver, esm.sh or jspm that can take care of that for you, then all you need to do is adding a tiny [importmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap)

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "tonweb": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tonweb@0.0.62/+esm"
  }
}
</script>

<script type="module">
  import Tonweb from 'tonweb'
  console.log(new Tonweb())
</script>
```

notices that i added `/+esm` at the end of the url, that means it will transform the module to esm. so

```js
import TonWeb from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tonweb@0.0.62/src/index.min.js/+esm'
```

would work just as well